# How to prove that 2SAT $\in$ P

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, np-complete

I want to understand the proof in the following [link](https://www.iitg.ac.in/deepkesh/CS301/assignment-2/2sat.pdf) for 2SAT $\in$ P...
What for the need of the last corollary?
Wouldn't be enought to just prove the case for the graph with the help of the path search?
Furthermore, is the proof for the corollary correct? I mean over there we have only an algorithm for a pseudo code...

## Edit

About the case#2 for the Claim 2. How can we prove the contradiction? Because it seems to me that it is actually true...

I write here my thoughts:

However, since $x$ is now $FALSE$, all literals on the path from $x$ to $α$ (including $α$) must be $FALSE$. Likewise, all literals on the path from $β$ to $¬x$ (including $β$) must be $TRUE$  (because $¬x=TRUE$). This results in an edge between $α$ and $β$, with $α=FALSE$ and $β=TRUE$. Consequently the disjunction $(¬α∨β)$ becomes $TRUE$, asserting our assumption that there is a satisfactory assignment $ρ(x_1,x_2,…,x_n)$ to $Ψ$. So the contradiction   ***fails***.

Could someone tell me please what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything prior to the corollary proves that the *decision problem* 2SAT is in P, namely checking whether or not a 2SAT formula is satisfiable as a yes or no question. The corollary extends this result into a polynomial-time algorithm to actually find such an assignment.

As for whether or not the proof of the corollary is "correct," there's not really much of a proof to verify the correctness of. In order to be "complete," the corollary should prove the correctness (and polynomial runtime) of its proposed algorithm. Fortunately, this isn't too hard (as a hint, show that once you check a solution exists, arbitrarily assigning one variable and following the graph never introduces a conflict).

EDIT: For your follow-up question, rather than considering the path from $x$ to $\lnot x$, consider the path from $\lnot x$ to $x$. Then if $\lnot x\to \dots\to\alpha\to\beta\to\dots\to x$, we can get $\alpha$ is true, $\beta$ is false, and derive the same contradiction as in case 1.

Comment: This exactly! And to stress, decision and search problems are not in general the same. Just b/c we can answer the decision problem efficiently does not necessarily mean we can solve the search problem in the same bounds (or even efficiently).

Comment: Hey, @ConnorGordon... Thanks for the reply

I have edited my question with another doubt involving the same problem

Comment: I edited my answer to address your follow-up question.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment, but unfortunately too long for a comment.

As additional intuition, 2SAT is actually $\textsf{NL}$-complete. The reduction from 2SAT to Path Finding in Directed Graphs is $\textsf{AC}^{0}$-computable (and hence, computable by $\textsf{NL}$). Now Path Finding in Directed Graphs is $\textsf{NL}$-complete. This gives us that 2SAT belongs to $\textsf{NL}$. For the lower bound ($\textsf{NL}$-hardness), we can take an undirected graph and recover a 2SAT formula (reverse the construction you've been referencing).

Given that 3SAT is $\textsf{NP}$-complete, I think showing that 2SAT is in $\textsf{P}$ on its own does little to help build intuition as to how far apart these problems are. The $\textsf{NL}$-completeness result is nice, since we now have some intuitive contrast between $\textsf{NP}$ and $\textsf{NL}$: namely, 3SAT vs. 2SAT.